# Deploying app on emulator failed with error "Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED"

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am trying to test my current source code which simply contains a few buttons with no listeners. Just to check if I am on the right way. I try to run my app on the emulator and I get error

```
[2014-02-03 21:19:10 - EngClalc] Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED
[2014-02-03 21:19:10 - EngClalc] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2014-02-03 21:19:10 - EngClalc] Launch canceled!
```

I checked the LogCat and what I see is

```
02-03 14:19:11.073: E/cutils-trace(765): Error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-03 14:19:11.953: D/AndroidRuntime(765): Calling main entry com.android.commands.pm.Pm
02-03 14:19:12.034: W/ActivityManager(290): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/EngClalc.apk
02-03 14:19:12.075: W/ActivityManager(290): No content provider found for permission revoke: file:///data/local/tmp/EngClalc.apk
02-03 14:19:12.075: I/PackageManager(290): Copying native libraries to /data/app-lib/vmdl924436775
02-03 14:19:12.097: W/PackageParser(290): /data/app/vmdl924436775.tmp (at Binary XML file line #16): <activity> does not have valid android:name
```

this is my android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="GreekAppsDev.engclalc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="GreekAppsDev.engclalc.Calc"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

as I am a noob in android development I do not understand what this error means or if more info is needed in order to fix the error.

I tried deleting the gen folder and it did not fix it.

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error:

```
<activity> does not have valid android:name
```

says that the issue is in the line where you define name for your activity:

```
 <activity
        android:name="GreekAppsDev.engclalc.Calc"
```

Because this is your main activity, and you've already specified a package, you don't have to it again package, so change the above line to:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".Calc"
```

Comment: truth is the manifest was created automatically I did not search it much. but it worked. Now I get a force close but that is another issue. Thanks

Comment: What's the logcat saying?

Comment: found it, I was searching for the screenwidth in dp before setcontentview